# Beautifulsoup4 syntax error when trying to run code

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, syntax-error

(im new to programming)

so im trying to make a web scraper, and I just installed bs4.

trying to do something as simple as finding and printing "x" thing, but when I try to run the code, it just comes up with an error, and I have no idea why (prob. Because  im new)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('NRGI.html', 'r') as f:
    doc = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')

print(doc)
```

but this error comes up:

```
>>> /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/jonasege/Desktop/Python/Web scraping/main.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/jonasege/Desktop/Python/Web scraping/main.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You have to run that command in the system shell (`$ `), not inside the Python REPL (`>>> `).

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the code shown

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you should first *read* your file f, and only then pass it to Beautiful Soup. Something like this:

```
with open('NRGI.html', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    doc = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
```